# How to get the html contents of one controller by the button click which lies in another controller

Tags: angularjs

i have two controllers, i am trying to access the html contents of second controller by the click of a button which is in first controller. i have tried using services,there is something that i am missing.

check the `plunker`(https://plnkr.co/edit/IGboL2tQGxwzJn1KhEAE?p=preview) for the code.

any suggestions?

Comment: in my plunkr alert box should display "two" instead of "one"

Answer (score 0):

1 : You can use $emitter methods or 
2 : Develop methods with $rootScope

so that you can call methods from another controllers .

Comment: i don't think you understood the question.i was able to call a function from another controller using service but contents of it are of the first controller only..where as i want to access that of second controller.